# How to find text sibiling span in Selenium

Tags: selenium

```
<div class="alertCount" tooltip="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="aa" title="" data-original-title="Bin">
<img src="sample/red.png" style="width:20px">
<span class="ng-binding" style="font-weight: bold; margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px">0</span>
</div>
<div class="alertCount" tooltip="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="aa" title="" data-original-title="Bin">
<img src="sample/green.png" style="width:20px">
<span class="ng-binding" style="font-weight: bold; margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px">0</span>
</div>
```

i want to print only text from red.png's div.

Comment: What code have you tried and what was the result? Before asking a question here you should have researched your own question and at least made an attempt to code the answer. Please post that code and how it's not working.

Comment: Hi jeffC..i used this code to solve my problem  String Text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='sample/red.png']/following-sibling::span")).getText();

Comment: If you found an answer, please post it as an answer and accept it so the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

That image doesn't actually contains the text but what I guess is that  its the following sibling **Span** which has a text '0' If I understood it correctly then use xpath as it is in below java code :

```
String Text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='sample/red.png']/following-sibling::span")).getText();
```

and print the Text.

Comment: Please accept and upvote the the answer Thulashi. In case if you want to know more about xpath and cssSelector path you can watch videos on this link. xpath: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67bzMdbhIuw css: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YhDz7OBOQ8

Comment: ok..do you have any idea mouse hover for particular height and width.

Comment: You can do it by this: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.moveByOffset(10, 10).build().perform();
  System.out.println("moved");
  Thread.sleep(10000);

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(""));
action.moveToElement(we, 158, 33).click().build().perform();
WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(""));
String toolTipText = toolTipElement.getText();System.out.println(toolTipText) Same way i am using but height and width is changed by dynamic?